# SSIS Visual Studio IDE will not stay still

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ide

Does anyone else have the problem with SSIS in Visual Studio 2019 (and earlier versions) where the screen bounces around and will not stay still as you make changes?  Is there a setting that you can off the (what I'm calling) active focus?

Comment: Not sure what you're describing but try toggling the state of hardware acceleration (Tools. Options, Auto adjust visual experience) and making sure you're current on patching for VS + SSDT

Comment: Nothing like that happened. try to check your memory and cpu usage.